# Capture webcam using ffmpeg-python library

Tags: python, ffmpeg, timestamp, webcam

Hi I'm attempting to capture a webcam stream with python using the ffmpeg-python wrapper library (https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)
I have a working ffmpeg command which is:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 352x288 -i /dev/video0 -vf "drawtext='fontfile=fonts/FreeSerif.ttf: text=%{pts} : \
x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1'" -an -y -t 15 videotests/out_localtime8.mp4
```

This captures 15s of video in resolution 352x288, and writes a timestamp in the bottom centre of the video.

To play with the ffmpeg-python library, I'm simply attempting to only get the drawtext filter working, here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ffmpeg
stream = ffmpeg.input('videotests/example.mov')
stream = ffmpeg.filter_(stream,'drawtext',("fontfile=fonts/FreeSerif.ttf:text=%{pts}"))
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, 'videotests/output4.mp4')
ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

The error is

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x561f59d494e0] Either text, a valid file or a timecode must be provided
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x561f59d39080] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile\\\=fonts/FreeSerif.ttf\\\:text\\\=%{pts}'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

The above appears to at least reach ffmpeg but the format of the arguments is incorrect, how to correct them?

Alternatively, when I attempting to split the argument to just pass one of them, I get a different error, as follows:

```
stream = ffmpeg.filter_(stream,'drawtext',('text=%{pts}'))
```

Error is

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ffmpeg', '-i', 'videotests/example.mov', '-filter_complex', "[0]drawtext=(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'text\\\\\\\\\\\\=%{pts}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\,)[s0]", '-map', '[s0]', 'videotests/output4.mp4']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

How come there are so many backslashes? Any advice on how to proceed please.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks user1767754 but that syntax is not relevant for the python wrapper library to ffmpeg.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the correct syntax eventually.  Here is a working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ffmpeg
stream = ffmpeg.input('videotests/example.mov')
stream = ffmpeg.filter_(stream,'drawtext',fontfile="fonts/hack/Hack-Regular.ttf",text="%{pts}",box='1', boxcolor='0x00000000@1', fontcolor='white')
stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, 'videotests/output6.mp4')
ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

The syntax is

```
ffmpeg.filter_(<video stream name>,'<filter name>',filter_parameter_name='value',<filter_parameter_name>=value)
```

Where necessary use quotes for the filter_parameter_name values.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: set environment variable for ffmpeg.

step 2: below code will help to to capture image as well as video using ffmpeg in python along with its current date and time.

```html
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import time
 
class Webcam:
 def Image(self):
  try:
   user = int(input("How many Images to be captured:"))
  except ValueError:
   print("\nPlease only use integers")

  for i in range (user):
   subprocess.call("ffmpeg -f vfwcap -vstats_file c:/test/log"+ datetime.now().strftime("_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") +".txt -t 10 -r 25 -i 0 c:/test/sample"+ datetime.now().strftime("_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") +".jpg")
   time.sleep(3)
   
 def Video(self):
  try:
   user = int(input("How many videos to be captured:"))
  except ValueError:
   print("\nPlease only use integers")

  for i in range (user):
   subprocess.call("ffmpeg -f vfwcap -vstats_file c:/test/log"+ datetime.now().strftime("_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") +".txt -t 10 -r 25 -i 0 c:/test/sample"+ datetime.now().strftime("_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") +".avi")
   time.sleep(5)
   
Web=Webcam()

print ("press 1 to capture image")
print ("Press 2 to capture video")
choose = int(input("Enter choice:"))
if choose == 1:
 Web.Image()
elif choose == 2:
 Web.Video()
else:
 print ("wrong choose")
```

import subprocess : Is use to call FFMPEG command.

**subprocess** is the in-build module provided by python